# Android russian dictionary to check if noun exsts

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary

I want to know if there is any dictionary that I can use in my app offline to check if certain word exists?
In sqllite maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything, so I parsed the dictionary from txt file myself.